# Bank account class with 2 child class not showing results

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the interest and the total balance but I don't understand whats wrong in my code

```
public class Account {

    private double bal;  //The current balance
    private int accnum;  //The account number

    public String owner;
    public int balance;
  
    public Account() {
        
    }
    
    public Account(int a)
    {    
        bal=0.0;
        accnum=a;
        
    }
    
    public void deposit(double sum)
    {
    if (sum>0) 
        bal+=sum;             
    else
        System.err.println("Account.deposit(...): "
                   +"cannot deposit negative amount.");    
    }
    
    public void withdraw(double sum)
    {
    if (sum>0)
        bal-=sum;    
    else
        System.err.println("Account.withdraw(...): "
                   +"cannot withdraw negative amount.");    
    }
    
    public double getBalance()
    {
        return bal;
    }
    
    public double getAccountNumber()
    {
        return accnum;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Acc: " + accnum + ": " + "Balance: " + bal;    
    }
    
    public final void print()
    {
    //Don't override this,
    //override the toString method
    System.out.println( toString() );    
    }   
}
```

Class `SavingsAccount`

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account{
    
    private  double monthlyInterestRate;

    public SavingsAccount( int a, double mI) 
    {
        super(a);
        monthlyInterestRate = mI;
    }
    
    public double getInterest() 
    {
        return  monthlyInterestRate*super.getBalance();
    }
    
    
    public double totalBalance(){
        return super.getBalance() + getInterest();
    }
    
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Interest: " + getInterest()  + "\n" + 
                "Total balance: " + totalBalance();
    }
    

}
```

Class `CurrentAccount`

```
public class CurrentAccount extends Account {

    private double overdraftLimit;

    public CurrentAccount() {}

    public CurrentAccount(int a, double overdraftLimit) 
    {

        super(a);
        setOverdraftLimit(overdraftLimit);
    }

    public void setOverdraftLimit(double overdrafLimit) 
    {
         this.overdraftLimit = overdrafLimit ;
    }

    public double getOverdraftLimit() 
    {
        return overdraftLimit;
    }

    public String toString()
    
        {
            return  "Overdraft limit: " + overdraftLimit;
        }



}
```

Class `AccountMain`

```
public class AccountMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        Account ac = new Account(100555);
        ac.deposit(2000);
        SavingsAccount sa = new SavingsAccount(100555, 0.2);
        CurrentAccount ca = new CurrentAccount(100555, 800);
        
        System.out.println(ac.toString());
        System.out.println(sa.toString());
        System.out.println(ca.toString());
```

The output is

> Acc: 100555: Balance: 2000.0
>
> Interest: 0.0
>
> Total balance: 0.0
>
> Overdraft limit: 800.0

Comment: did you try the debugger?

Comment: yes but i dont get any error

Comment: This is far too much code, try to find out where things go wrong and ask again

Comment: You call `deposit` on the object `ac` - why should the other two be affected by that?

Comment: because I need initial balance + interest

Comment: You have created 3 different objects, ac, sa and ca and in toString you are printing different data. this is not correct - you are expecting ac : gives account number and balance,  sa = Interest and total balance and ca for overdraft limit

Comment: i just need to get the balance from Account.java than add interest to get total balance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

> public SavingsAccount( int a, double mI)  {
>       super(a);
>       monthlyInterestRate = mI; }

You are calling

> super(a);

in super that is account you have

> public Account(int a) {
>       bal=0.0;
>       accnum=a; }

So your balance is 0 hence public double getInterest() return 0 because 
**monthlyInterestRate*super.getBalance();**

 equal to **monthlyInterestRate * 0**